# Is there a way to find a specific file and then change into the directory containing it in one go?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, find

I'm looking for a way to find what I know will be a unique file, and then change into the directory containing that file. Something along the lines of:

```
find . -name 'Subscription.java' | xargs cd
```

Or:

```
find . -name 'Subscription.java' -exec cd {} \;
```

I know this won't work because it's both trying to `cd` supplying the entire absolute path, which contains the file, and also because `xargs` can't do any built in shell commands, but you get the point of what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
cd $(find . -name Subscription.java | xargs dirname)
```

Comment: Exactly the command I was looking for. I knew it was out there, but didn't know what the damn command was. Awesome. Thanks.

Comment: And for anyone else that didn't know how to do this, I just slapped it into a shell function:  
function fcd()  
{  
  cd $(find . -name $1 | xargs dirname)  
}

Comment: `cd $(dirname $(find . -name $1 | sed 1q))` deals with non-unique names by going to the first one found and goes home if the name is not found.  It also demonstrates nested use of `$(...)` which is why that notation is preferred over backticks.  You might prefer '`sed '2,$d'`' since it avoids SIGPIPE errors messing with `find`.

Comment: Nice with the sed 1q. I need to look more into sed - I don't know much about it.

Comment: Other useful variations if you want to go to the directory where an executable in the path is: `wcd () { cd $(dirname $(which $1)); }` or `wcd () { cd $(dirname $(type -p $1)); }` or `wcd () { local dir=$(type -P $1); [[ -z $dir ]] && dir='.'; cd "${dir%/*}"; }`. The last one doesn't spawn any externals and doesn't change directories if the name is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Any attempt to script a `cd` command must ensure that the command is run in the current shell. Otherwise if run in a child shell, it will not work as you need as the parent current working directory will not be changed.

GNU find has -printf which can be used print the directory of any found files. The output of find can be passed to `cd` with Command Substitution.

```
cd $(find . -name Subscription.java -printf '%h\n')
```

cd (in bash) ignores extra arguments so if multiple files are found, cd will change into the directory of the first found file.

Answer (score 0):

Linux/OSX (alternative answer):

```
cd `find . -name Subscription.java | xargs dirname`
```